# Python/Django - How to decrease memory usage when Importing CSV into Database?

Tags: python, django, csv, memory-management, memory-leaks

This is what I'm doing:

```
reader = csv.reader(file)
fields = ["row_id","second_field","third_field",...]

for index, row in enumerate(reader):
    mapped_row = dict(zip(fields,row))

    DataEntry.objects.get_or_create(row_id=mapped_row["row_id"], defaults={
         second_field = mapped_row["second_field"],
         third_field = mapped_row["third_field"],
         ...
    })
```

Memory blows up way out of proportion!

After 50000+ rows system is already using **4GB** and then starts swapping on the HDD, and Python isn't freeing up unsusued memory.

---

I've tried adding the following on each line to no avail

```
 del index
 del row
 del mapped_row
```

---

I'm using Python 2.7.5 and Django 1.5.

---

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Did you try read using a buffer or reading / writing in blocks, for instance over 10000 more o less each time ?

Comment: @ManuParra thanks for suggestion! As CSV reader is a generator, shouldn't it make chunks unnecessary?

Comment: But, really you need have all data in memory, because you are storing then the  object DataEntry.

Comment: is it python consuming all the memory? what is your db engine?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are reading all the data into a dictionary before writing any of it. There is no obvious reason to do that. Try reading / writing in different sized chunks (1 row at a time, 10, 100 etc.) and see which chunk size provides the memory and speed performance you prefer.

Comment: I'm creating a dictionary to abstract the second part of the process as `row[45], row[23], row[127], ...` isn't very readable and maintainable. I imagine that Python should garbage collect that dictionary after the iteration and `del mapped_row` should solve that in anycase.

Comment: Doesn't CSV reader being a generator avoid having to read it in chunks? Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: The main issue is, there's no reason to read all data into a dict before writing any of it to the DB -- that maximizes memory use. The issue around chunks is, depending on how your DB connection is configured, writing a row at a time might make the overall operation slower than necessary. Writing in chunks may speed up the operation. Best to experiment.